# What type of data is in the default mysql DB vs information_schema

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble finding info that explains the purpose of the default mysql database vs information_schema.  Users and passwords are in mysql in the users tables, but what other types of data goes into these two dbs and where is this behavior configured?  If possible please provide a quick summary and a link to documentation that discuses this.

Answer (score 0):

In the DBA StackExchange I answer this question

- [**How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3336/877)

explaining how the tables in that schema are populated with metadata about the physical files of the tables and intrinsic statistics.

I also answered questions like these in the DBA StackExchange

- [**Backup and restore “mysql” database**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31023/877)
- [**What is the mysql.db table used for?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/what-is-the-mysql-db-table-used-for/13350#13350)
- [**MySQL : Why are there “test” entries in mysql.db?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)
- [**Is this a normal set of MySQL privileges?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/is-this-a-normal-set-of-mysql-privileges/5624#5624)
- [**Secure method beside phpMyAdmin for remote mysql**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17076/secure-method-beside-phpmyadmin-for-remote-mysql/17110#17110)

concerning the mysql schema's tables in terms of security.

I also answered these

- [**Create a custom log table in MySQL**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/create-a-custom-log-table-in-mysql/8117#8117) for `mysql.slow_log`
- [**MySQL general log**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/mysql-general-log/12672#12672) for `mysql.general_log`

I hope these answers helped ...